# Recursive function and this D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, recursion

I have an array of points with `point={x,y,nextPoint}`. The aim is to draw a line between each point and move a circle on it. The `nextPoint` of the last point in the array is null.

I was able to move a circle by calling `[number of points]-1` methods on the point. That's not flexible at all and I want to do it recursively. I'm creating a circle like that:

```
function addCercle() {
  var ret = svg.append("circle") //svg is declared before
    .attr("cx", points[0].x) // points = the array of points
    .attr("cy", points[0].y)
    .attr("r", "3%");
  return ret;
}
```

The function that is not working is this:

```
function move(p) {
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
    p = d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(speed) //
      .attr("cx", points[i].x)
      .attr("cy", points[i].y);
  }
}
```

And i would like to call it like that to make the circle run on all the line:

```
var test = addCercle();
console.log(test);
move(test);
```

Could someone explain me what I have to change in my function move? Or in the call perhaps?

Comment: What is `this` in your scope? Shouldn't it be `d3.select(p)`?

Comment: if I understand what you want to do it is this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868 "Point-Along-Path Interpolation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your `move` function recursive, you need to call it from within itself. As always, there are numerous ways to do it, but if you have an array of points, you could either pass in the array of points, or pass in the current position in the array of points. Here is an example where you pass in an array of points:

```
// p is the element being moved, points is the array of points
function move(p, points) {
  if (points.length > 0) { // one point or more in the array => move the element
    p.transition()
      .duration(speed) //
      .attr("cx", points[0].x)
      .attr("cy", points[0].y)
      // when the transition ends, call this function with the array of points minus the first point
      .on('end', () => move(p, points.slice(1)));
  }
}

const arrayOfPoints = [{x: 100, y: 200},{x: 200, y: 200}, {x: 300, y: 300}]
// call the function
move(circle, arrayOfPoints);
```

Working example where I've generated an array of points and then moved a circle along the path described by those points:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg'),
radius = 100,
pts = d3.range(0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.01 * Math.PI) // NOTE: this produces an array
        .map( d => d3.pointRadial(d, radius) ),// of arrays; slightly different
                                               // to your data structure
speed = 50

function addCercle(points) {
  var ret = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(150,150)')
    .append("circle") //svg is declared before
    .attr("cx", points[0][0]) // points = the array of points
    .attr("cy", points[0][1])
    .attr("r", "3%");
  return ret;
}

function move(p, points) {
  if (points.length > 0) {
    p.transition()
      .duration(speed) //
      .attr("cx", points[0][0])
      .attr("cy", points[0][1])
      .on('end', () => move(p, points.slice(1)));
  }
}

var test = addCercle(pts);
move(test, pts);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
```

You can produce smoother paths and animations by tweening the transitions.

Here's a slightly altered example that follows the same principles but uses the data structure you describe in your question; all that has changed is the way that the function sets the `cx` and `cy` values and how it decides whether or not there are more points to display.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg'),
radius = 300,
pts = d3.range(0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.01 * Math.PI).map( d => d3.pointRadial(d, radius) ),
speed = 50

function makeWeirdDataStructure ( pts ) {
  return {
    x: pts[0][0],
    y: pts[0][1],
    nextPt: pts.length > 1 ? makeWeirdDataStructure( pts.slice(1) ) : null
  }
}

function addCercle(points) {
  var ret = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(400,400)')
    .append("circle") //svg is declared before
    .attr("cx", points.x) // points = the array of points
    .attr("cy", points.y)
    .attr("r", "3%");
  return ret;
}

function move(p, points) {
  if ( points !== null ) {
    p.transition()
      .duration(speed) //
      .attr("cx", points.x)
      .attr("cy", points.y)
      .on('end', () => move(p, points.nextPt));
  }
}

var wds = makeWeirdDataStructure(pts)
var test = addCercle(wds);
move(test, wds);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
```

Comment: This looks great to me but with your examples i have this error `d3.pointRadial is not a function` how could i fix it? And what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: it turns an angle and a radius into cartesian coordinates. You shouldn't need it -- I only used it to generate a set of points to demonstrate the recursive function.